# Call a PostgreSQL function in bash script

Tags: bash, postgresql

How can I call a PostgreSQL function in a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U usr -d db1
select firstfunction();
EXIT;
EOF
```

This connects me to my database in the command line (Putty), but it doesn't run the function. When I exit with (\q) I get an error "syntax error near unexpected token exit"

Comment: `psql -U usr -d db1 -c "select firstfunction();"`

Comment: Thank you. It works!! Is it possible to return a code error in a log file if it terminates unexpectedly?

Comment: @user3365621
I don't have psql but this is not posgres related actually - if psql uses standard stream, then you can redirect it:

`psql -U usr -d db1 -c "select firstfunction():" 1 > output_file 2 > error_file`

This is called standard streams redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the redirect in from EOF..  ie  << EOF

```
#!/bin/bash
psql -U usr -d db1  << EOF
select firstfunction();
EXIT;
EOF
```